# Execution fail with Value::getName and Value::HasName (LLVM)

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Im doing a program to list all function calls of .ll files.

Here is my code:

```
void foo (const Module *M) {
    for (const Function &F : *M) {
        for (const BasicBlock &BB : F) {
            for (const Instruction &I : BB) {
                // CallInst: represents a function call
                if (dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I)) {
                    StringRef name = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I)->getCalledFunction()->getName();
                    std::cout << name.str() << "\n";
                ...
                ...
```

The problem is in line 7. 
In this file: https://pastebin.com/vYhVf4qS

When my program with all my test files, there is no problem, but when I test with this one, this error appears:

```
#0 0x0000000000427d10 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) /ubuntu/llvm/llvm-3.9.0.src/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:402:0
#1 0x00000000004280af PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) /ubuntu/llvm/llvm-3.9.0.src/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:470:0
#2 0x0000000000426157 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() /ubuntu/llvm/llvm-3.9.0.src/lib/Support/Signals.cpp:44:0
#3 0x0000000000427557 SignalHandler(int) /ubuntu/llvm/llvm-3.9.0.src/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:256:0
#4 0x00007fbde269c390 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x11390)
#5 0x000000000040b402 llvm::Value::hasName() const /ubuntu/llvm/llvm-3.9.0.src/include/llvm/IR/Value.h:233:0
#6 0x000000000040afa7 buildFunctionsCallMap[abi:cxx11](llvm::Module const*) /foo/PrintCallingFunctions.cpp:50:0
#7 0x000000000040b168 printCallingFuntions(llvm::Module const*) /foo/PrintCallingFunctions.cpp:75:0
#8 0x00000000004070bf main ...../main.cpp:76:0
#9 0x00007fbde15f3830 __libc_start_main /build/glibc-9tT8Do/glibc-2.23/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:325:0
#10 0x0000000000406bb9 _start (../../../build/bin/foo+0x406bb9)
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: ../../../build/bin/foo QLA_D3_c1_veq_V_dot_V.ll
```

The problem seems to be when I call to getName() function, that calls hasName(), and this last one gives the error, but I dont understand why and I dont know to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that `getCalledFunction()` returns null if the call is an indirect call through a function pointer. I looked in your IR file and the calls look like this:

```
%14 = call i32 (i32, { double, double }*, ...) bitcast (i32 (...)* @__alignx to i32 (i32, { double, double }*, ...)*)(i32 16, { double, double }* %13)
```

The call target is a bitcast constant expression, so that's likely the issue. You can use `getCalledValue()` instead -- in this case it would return a `ConstantExpr` representing the bitcast, and you could try to use `stripPointerCasts()` to get at the function itself.

Comment: Wow, thanks for help, it's fixed now using getCalledValue(). I'm starting at llvm and I could not have fixed it. Thanks again!